# Using Boostrap in Wordpress theme wp nav

Tags: menuitem, bootstrapping, wp-nav-walker

Can anyone tell me how to integrate Bootstrap into my Wordpress theme for the navigation menus? I just want a simple explanation that is easy to follow because I am a beginner coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great tutorial located here https://a1websitepro.com/boostrap-nav-menu-wordpress/ You can use this in your header.php or wherever you are putting you menu.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default"><div class="container-fluid">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container' => 'ul', 
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'menu_id' => 'bootmenu',
    'echo' => true, 
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 
     ) );?>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This worked perfectly. Thank you.